# Linq: Get all document with sort at mongodb

Tags: mongodb, linq, mongodb-query

this is my document :

```
{
 "BusinessCode": "8545",
 "CreationDateTime": "/Date(1487417012464)/",
 "DeviceId": "",
 "Distributions": null,
 "EventData": [
      {
       "Children": null,
       "Key": "LogID",
       "Value": "496a506b4301"
      }
 ],
 "EventId": "events.login",
 },...
```

How could I get all documents into my collection with sorting by linq?

this is my earlier query:

```
var messagess = GetDbMongo().GetCollection<Message>(DB_COLLECTION_MESSAGES)
                .Find(Builders<Message>.Filter.And()).Sort(sortt).Limit(count <= 0 ? 10 : count).ToList();
```

Comment: Sort on what? It is missing the most important part of your question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I got it wrong but your idea of sort "by linq" is wrong. Sorting using Linq is done in memory. Using `OrderBy` will cause the whole collection to be enumerated at once which is very bad. Instead, use Mongo to do the sorting for you. This will be faster and you'll be using the server resources, not your app's. But it seems that you are already using .Sort on the Collection so.. not sure what you really want.

But, you could re-write your code to sort using Mongo by doing this:

```
var collection = GetDbMongo().GetCollection<Message>(DB_COLLECTION_MESSAGES); 

// Empty filter to get all records
var emptyFilter = Builders<Message>.Filter.Empty;

// Choose which field of Message type you want to sort for
var sort = Builders<Message>.Sort.Ascending(p => p.Name);

var messagess = collection.Find(emptyFilter)
    .Sort(sort)
    .Limit(count <= 0 ? 10 : count)
    .ToList();
```

If you are not familiar with how Linq operators work regarding being "lazy" or not, this is a good blog post from Jon Skeet: [Just how lazy are you?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/03/25/just-how-lazy-are-you/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
var messagess = GetDbMongo()
                   .GetCollection<Message>(DB_COLLECTION_MESSAGES)
                   .FindAll()
                   .Sort(sortt)
                   .ToList();
```